# How do I get the previous message(Telegram Bot using JAVA)

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I am trying to get the previous Message. First the User ist sending Message: "Search Student". Then the Bot replies on that message with: "Enter the name of student". Then the user has to write something and after that I would like to call a specific function.

Here is my code:

```
switch (message.getText()){
      case "Search Student":
            sendMsg(message, "Enter the name of Stunde: ");
            //And somewhere here i would like to call a function that is searching for a student (I have
            //already created the function)
            break;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced such a problem recently and I have recreated this method. But I am not sure if this solution is a good one! I also believe that there is no very specific answer to this question.

The idea is to write the last action of the user/student/profile to the database by opening one table called 
`telegram_action` table including following columns:

```
telegram action {
  actionName: String; // your case, the action is "Search Student"
  messageId: Integer; // message Id that you want to as previous one
}
```

Your changed code:

```
switch (message.getText()){
      case "Search Student":
            sendMsg(message, "Enter the name of Stunde: ");
            //And somewhere here i would like to call a function that is searching for a student (I have
            //already created the function)
            createTelegramUserAction("Search Student", message.getMessageId());
            break;
      default:
              //I didn't implement this method, idea is simply choose from TelegramAction database
             //that ACTIVE STATUS or not deleted one(there will be only one) with action name "Search Student";
             // Then you will have previous **mesageId** and you will know this message is action of Searching student
             // every time you create new action, `createTelegramAction function` will delete you previous actions, don't worry!
              actionCheck(message);

}
```

So, I created one `createTelegramUserAction()` method to save last action as following:

```
 public void createTelegramAction(String actionName, Integer messageId, Long chatId) {

            // Disable or Delete all previous actions from database before creating new one!!!
            disableAllActions("Search Students");

            // create action that Student wants search, in your case actionName = "Search Student";
            // save this action to telegram_action table, **didn't implemented**
            create(actionName, messageId);
}



public void disableAllActions(String actionName) {
    // Note that I have chosen to disable the status in here, however you can simply delete all actions
    // In my case, it was necessary to save last action
    // In Deleting case you don't need ActionStatus enum

    // ActionStatus is enum with values {ACTIVE and INACTIVE}
        List<TelegramAction> telegramActions = telegramActionRepository
            .findAllByActionNameAndUserActionStatus(actionName, ActionStatus.ACTIVE);

        for (TelegramAction telegramAction : telegramActions) {
            // here you can either delete the actions or make INACTIVE.
            telegramAction.setActionStatus(ActionStatus.INACTIVE);
            telegramActionRepository.save(telegramAction);
        }
}
```

Note that this `createTelegramAction` method can be used for other methods as a generic method. But there is always space for improving the idea to make it more generic functions

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement it like this)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(message.getReplyToMessage().getText().contains("Enter the name of Schueler:")){
        List<Schueler> foundSchueler = search.searchSchueler(message.getText(), schueler);
        String foundSchuelerStr = "Found Schueler: \n\n";
        for (Schueler s: foundSchueler) {
            foundSchuelerStr += s.toString();
        }
        sendMsg(message, foundSchuelerStr);
    }
```

This is my solution, and it works fantastic!
You simply have to check if the user had replied on message with a specific text